# memcpy vs pointer cast for reading BLE sensor float

Tags: c, pointers, memcpy, bluetooth-lowenergy

I came across two solutions for reading the float value of a BLE sensor. The memcpy method is straightforward and makes sense, however the other method I came across is not very clear to me. Can someone clarify exactly how the pointer casting method works?

```
    // Represents data read from BLE device. Float value of 1.5
    uint32_t data = 0x3fc00000;
    float sensorValue;

    // Memcpy method, makes sense and is straightforward
    memcpy(&sensorValue, &data, sizeof(sensorValue));

    // Works, but don't fully understand exactly how
    sensorValue = *(float *)&data;
```

Comment: Both invoke undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Olaf care to elaborate? What would be the correct way to get the float value then?

Comment: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p6 . To be strictly conforming, you can use functions of the standard library and normal operators. You can also check the math lib if there are reinterpretation functions. I'm well aware this is a dilemma. But note you don't even specify if the float-format is the same on your platform and from the sensor. Not to mention alignment and endianess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

&data is a pointer to a uint32_t.  So, (float *)&data casts it as a pointer to a float.  Finally, *(float *)&data dereferences that pointer.

You could do the same thing as:

```
uint32_t *ui32 = &data
float *f = (float *) ui32;
sensorValue = *f;
```

But, the exact behavior is likely to be platform dependent.

Comment: No, the behaviour is undefined. Violation of effective type rule.