# memcpy vs pointer casts vs something better

Tags: c, pointers, deserialization

I am decoding a serial protocol. The data is sent from a device in little-endian format over the wire. I have hacked together two different ways of doing it but they both seem very "hacky".

```
// Example of data that is read in from serial port
unsigned char data[8] = {0xb0,0x00,0x44,0x04,0x4a,0x0f,0x4d,0x30};

// This will pull out the number that I need (on a little-endian machine)
uint16_t a;
a = *(uint16_t*)&data[2];

//So will this, but it makes an extra call to memcpy(). (again, only on a little-endian machine)
uint16_t b;
memcpy((void*)&b,(void*)&data[2],sizeof(b));
```

I have code that I can plug in to swap bytes for big endian machines

```
    #ifdef WORDS_BIGENDIAN
    unsigned char *word_ptr;
    word_ptr = &data[2];
    // swap bytes, standard XOR swap algorithm
    word_ptr[0] = word_ptr[0] ^ word_ptr[1];
    word_ptr[1] = word_ptr[1] ^ word_ptr[0];
    word_ptr[0] = word_ptr[0] ^ word_ptr[1];
    #endif /* WORDS_BIGENDIAN */
```

An older question brought this up: [memcpy vs pointer cast for reading BLE sensor float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36185972/memcpy-vs-pointer-cast-for-reading-ble-sensor-float?r=SearchResults&s=3|92.7184) but the accepted answer only confirmed that it could work on certain platforms and comments indicated the behavior was undefined. What is a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normal procedure would be:

```
uint16_t a = data[2] + data[3] * 0x100u;
```

Some people prefer bitshift instead of multiplication but the result is the same.

The memcpy version probably doesn't "make an extra call to memcpy",  memcpy optimization is a pretty basic and widespread compiler feature.  But it has different behaviour depending on endianness of the local machine.

The `*(uint16_t) *` version does cause undefined behaviour as you say.

The XOR swap is considered poor form and it's better to swap using a temporary variable . Write simple and maintanable code and let the compiler do its job.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks also for the tip on XOR swap. Now I just need to read up on pointer alignment to understand why the undefined behavior works so often.

Comment: @JacobGeigle It appears to work because the compiler vendors know that there is a whole lot of this code out there in the wild and they'll get a bunch of complaints if the code stops working

Comment: @JacobGeigle well that depends on your messaging format

Comment: Assuming the next 4 bytes were a float value in correct byte order.

Comment: @JacobGeigle `memcpy` seems like the natural solution if you know the order is correct, although that is not reliable in general (typically you would have a fixed network protocol and various clients that might have different local representations)